# How do I use the backtrace of an error to debug code in fortran?

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, gfortran

I am very new to programming. Can you please explain what these errors mean? And how I can use them to debug my code?

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x106df59ac
#1  0x106df4d53
#2  0x7fff76a68b5c
#3  0x1059d27fd
#4  0x1059e58d0
#5  0x1059e1f8b
#6  0x1059de707
#7  0x1059de7ff
#8  0x1059dfd08
#9  0x10580734d
#10  0x10581c137
#11  0x1058995af
#12  0x1058b6b3e
#13  0x1058a11ce
#14  0x10576fb84
#15  0x10574729e
#16  0x10577b210
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [understanding stack trace of a segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726132/understanding-stack-trace-of-a-segmentation-fault)

Comment: Those symbols are addresses and are almost impossible to interpret  directly. Compile with `-g` to get meaningful source code locations. Compile with `-g -Wall -fcheck=all` to enable warnings and runtime error checking. That can reveal many types of errors.

Comment: As @Vladimir notes, those a list of addresses.  If you compiled with gfortran (which I'm guessing you did), then it also means that you don't have libunwind available.  libunwind would translated some or all of the addresses to symbols.  Follow Vladimir suggests for debugging the program.